# "target contains C++ module sources which are not supported by the generator"

Tags: c++, cmake, c++20

I have some problems getting anything to compile using modules for C++20 with VSCode, CMake (3.25.0-rc3), and G++ on an M1 macbook with (from what I can tell) Unix Makefiles. In fact, I'm not even able to get past the CMake's generation phase, as every time I try I get the error "target contains C++ module sources which are not supported by the generator." Is there something simple I'm missing? I'm currently trying to use Bill Hoffman's setup in his CppCon talk that was uploaded yesterday. (https://youtu.be/5X803cXe02Y?t=2288)

my CMakeLists.txt:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(TryingModules CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_CMAKE_API "3c375311-a3c9-4396-a187-3227ef642046")

set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_DYNDEP 1)
string(CONCAT CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_SCANDEP_SOURCE
  "<CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER> <DEFINES> <INCLUDES> <FLAGS> -E -x c++ <SOURCE>"
  " -MT <DYNDEP_FILE> -MD -MF <DEP_FILE>"
  " -fmodules-ts -fdep-file=<DYNDEP_FILE> -fdep-output=<OBJECT> -fdep-format=trtbd"
  " -o <PREPROCESSED_SOURCE>")
set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_MAP_FORMAT "g++")
set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_MAP_FLAG "-fmodules-ts -fmodule-mapper=<MODULE_MAP_FILE> -fdep-format=trtbd -x c++")


set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_MAP_FORMAT "g++")
set(CMAKE_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX_MODULE_FLAG
    "${compiler_flags_for_module_map} -fmodule-mapper=<MODULE_MAP_FILE>")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fmodules-ts")

add_library(TryingModules)
target_link_libraries(TryingModules)

target_sources(TryingModules PUBLIC FILE_SET cxx_modules TYPE CXX_MODULES FILES moduleTest.cpp)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main TryingModules)
```

my main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

import moduleTest;

int main(int, char**) {
    SayHello();
}
```

and my moduleTest.cpp:

```cpp
export module moduleTest;

#include <iostream>

export void SayHello()
{
    std::cout << "Hello :)" << '\n';
}
```

the full output:

```
[main] Configuring folder: TryingModules
[proc] Executing command: /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli
-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/opt/homebrew/bin/aarch64-apple-darwin21-gcc-12
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/local/bin/g++ -S/Users/rooster/Documents/TryingModules -B/Users/rooster/Documents/TryingModules/build -G "Unix Makefiles"
[cmake] CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:26 (target_sources):
[cmake]   CMake's C++ module support is experimental.  It is meant only for
[cmake]   experimentation and feedback to CMake developers.
[cmake] This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
[cmake]
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- Configuring done [cmake] CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
[cmake]   The "TryingModules" target contains C++ module sources which are not
[cmake]   supported by the generator
[cmake]
[cmake]
[cmake] -- Generating done
[cmake] CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
[proc] The command: /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake
--no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/opt/homebrew/bin/aarch64-apple-darwin21-gcc-12
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/local/bin/g++ -S/Users/rooster/Documents/TryingModules -B/Users/rooster/Documents/TryingModules/build -G "Unix Makefiles" exited with code: 1 and signal: null
```

I've tried different permutations of the file extensions (`.cpp`, `.cppm`, `.ixx`, `.cxx`, etc.) on main and moduleTest (updating the `CMakeLists.txt` accordingly) and I've tried regenerating the project multiple times. It seems like actual module support is still a ways off, so I may be barking up the entirely wrong tree here- trying to learn it as the thing is being built around me. Any help is appreciated, and if I need to provide any more information or anything just let me know.

Comment: "*i'm currently tring to use bill hoffman's setup in his Cppcon talk that was uploaded yesterday.*" I hope that he didn't use the code you've shown above, with the `#include` in the wrong place.

Comment: oh, he most definitely did not hahah!! thank you for pointing that out; i'm very new to c++ so i appreciate the learning opportunity :)

Comment: if you don't mind my asking, where should i put the `#include` statement? and what are the drawbacks of where i've put it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ninja build as a generator.

```
cmake -GNinja .
```

Regarding the includes, I believe your moduleTest.cpp should look like this:

```
module;

#include <iostream>

export module moduleTest;

export void SayHello()
{
    std::cout << "Hello :)" << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This answer could be improved by explaining why the asker's generator didn't work- perhaps with some reference to official documentation stating something like current limitiations. It could also probably give some brief explanation as to what the [global module fragment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules#Global_module_fragment) is.